# RDBMS vs NoSQL for CRM, CMS and other financial Systems

Tags: mysql, mongodb, couchdb, rdbms, nosql

I've read the whole SQL vs NoSql stuff out there in the Internet (spent a few days on it so I have rights to call it that way :) ) and still have a feeling I'm far away from being able to decide wich platform our products shall go with.
We're about to start designing a new set of products that mostly fit CRM/CMS categories, I'd say several B2B, B2C, B2E, E-Commerce as well as other financial and banking apps. So it's gonna be a complex system with dozens of databases solving different tasks. Let's concentrate on the DB area. I found [this](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2013/03/25/a-move-into-the-modern-web-world-nosql-the-enterprise/) article is particularly interesting for DB systems in the world of enterprise. So the actual problem is:

***Is it better to stay with good old RDBMS such as MySql (yes, it has to be open-source, that's the only requirement) or start off with NoSQL such as MongoDB/CouchDB*** (I guess Cassandra is too scalable for CRM, it's not going to be a very distributed and heavily clustered system. Up to 4 strong guys will do the job perfectly)???

As additional details I can say that a lot of media stuff and docs will be engaged in the system, this is a must for stores, markets, HR systems. And that the consumers of the storage will be web apps mainly.

***Would it be better to split the DB back-end into two parts: RDBMS serving relational data and NoSQL for the media storage?***

What you think and if you have examples or such an experience any help will just extremely help to avoid future problems. So Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: These questions are not normally a good fit SO but RDBMS normally win for finanicial systems since they are orientated around ACID and consistent multi document transactions etc etc etc

Comment: OK, then what about the media/doc part?

Comment: NoSQL could be used, however, I would use a CDN for media and doc storage tbh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are NoSQL (NewSQL) databases that are fully ACID compliant that you could consider. I would use one of those to handle the transactional CRM data. There are simply too many benefits using these compared to traditional relational databases:

- Much better performance

  Schemaless

  Some let you remove the ORM completely and uses the created objects automatically

  Some have integrated web server with REST/JSON support, that would be nice for you since you will work with web apps for the end user.

The ACID part is very important if you will build a CRM. I once build a CRM system that uses a NoSQL database and the performance made it possible to add features we never would have considered if we had used a traditional RMDBMS.

I like the idea that you should put the media and documents into a CDN and then refer to them from your database.

Your open source requirement could be a bit of a showstopper though.

I wrote an article on the subject that you might give some advice in the topic of selecting a database:

http://www.ulitzer.com/node/2636237

Comment: Thanks, Niklas, I got back to this task. Could you tell me what NoSql DB you used for the CRM system in your case (even if it's a commercial product)? That would be a good help, since there are different choices out there.

Comment: @AsyncMind: We used Starcounter (www.starcounter.com). There is a public downloadable trial version directly on their homepage if you like to test.

Comment: You link is no longer valid. I'd like to read your article